# Algorithm to cover time periods

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory

I have a table with data that covers time periods.
The periods overlap.

I want to purge the data in order to save space, but without losing days of data.

Here is an example table:

```
Id | Start      | End
 1 | 2023.01.01 | 2023.01.05
 2 | 2023.01.03 | 2023.01.07
 3 | 2023.01.04 | 2023.01.09
 4 | 2023.01.07 | 2023.01.13
 5 | 2023.01.09 | 2023.01.14
 6 | 2023.01.12 | 2023.01.15
```

[image: Original Data]

In this example, I have several solutions :

```
 1. Clean 2 and 5
 2. Clean 3 and 5
```

[image: Data for solution 1]
[image: Data for solution 2]

The best solution is the second, because 2 and 3 don't have the same weight.

```
 - Weight of Id=2 : 5 days 
 - Weight of Id=3 : 6 days
```

So I will gain more space if I took the second solution.

I have millions of rows, so I need an efficient algorithm.

Note that sometimes I have intervals with no data.

Do you have a **name of algorithm to solve this problem** please ?

Comment: Are you asking for the algorithm or just the name of it?

Comment: Just the name please...Thanks for your answer.

Comment: must the remaining intervals overlap or is it sufficient if they touch? I mean, suppose the intervals are: from 1 to 3, from 2 to 5, from 4 to 6; can you eliminate the middle one?

Comment: two more questions: Your task is to minimize the overlap while keeping full coverage, correct? Why can't you simply ignore the "intervals with no data", and how are they different from zero-length intervals?

Comment: I have no idea why this question was downvoted and there is a vote to close. It's a clearly-stated (with one detail to clarify), interesting problem that appears to be a real application. Sybaris, can you elaborate on "intervals with no data", including what to do about them? Can you separate the problem into smaller problems at those intervals? I suggest you change your last sentence to just asking for an algorithm that will produce an optimal solution. I'm curious what the application is. Can you say anything about that?

Comment: More questions: For any two intervals [a, b] and [c, d]: Is it true that a != c and b != d? Is it true that, if a < c, then b < d?

Comment: More questions still: What approximate percentage of the covered days are covered by just one interval (i.e., are not overlaps)? In your example it would be 3 days out of 15 → 20%, but it seems that, if a longer period were considered, the percentage would be very small – unless the example was not typical. When you say "intervals with no data", can we just assume they are not there, possibly leaving a hole in the sequence of days?

Comment: @CarySwoveland : Yes, there is a real application that needs to be develop.
We have sometimes, some gaps, where on several days, we do not have data for these days.
But ultimately, we can say that we can do pre-processing to isolate packets of contiguous intervals. This simplifies the problem, and in addition we will work on smaller packets of invervalles, so the algorithm will be more efficient.

Comment: Concerning the application, devices record information on a personal smart card. When the card is full, the oldest information is overwritten by the most recent. People swipe these cards through readers that record this data, mostly every day, but there are no rules. And the entire smart card is saved in the database.
Which explains the frequent overlap.
The data is already all there in database. My job is just to clean.

Comment: @WalterTross :1°/ I have simplified the real need to simplify the question. In my case, I have date and times (hours, minutes, seconds...).
And they need to overlap.
So in your example, "from 1 to 3, from 2 to 5, from 4 to 6; can you eliminate the middle one", no I cannot eliminate de middle one.
2°/ Yes our task is to minimize the overlap while keeping full coverage
3°/ In my case, all intervals contains data.
4°/ "For any 2 intervals [a, b] and [c, d]" : We can have a=c.

Comment: @WalterTross : 5°/ I have some cases, where we have some intervals included into another interval. But we can assume that we will do some preprocessing to eliminate them.
6°/ On average, the card contains about 4 weeks of data, and often it is read every day. Some only have it read once every 2 weeks...
7°/ When you say "intervals with no data". Sometimes, we can have someone that will have no data for 3 months for example. His card is reset, but he keeps the same identifier. So we had a gap.

Answer (score 2):

If we separate all `N` time intervals like `[1..2],[3..3],[4..5]..[12..13],[14..14],[15..15]` for the first picture, we can build a net (kind of directed graph with source and sink), where edges from source to intervals above have capacity 1, edges from intervals to time periods (covering intervals) have capacity 1, edges from time periods to sink have large enough (`N`) capacity, and cost of the last edges correspond to period weight.

So [Minimum-cost flow problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum-cost_flow_problem) providing amount of flow `N`